# as3 draw circle class error

Tags: actionscript-3, class, events, listener

I am trying to create an event listener in a custom class.  I have seen this in books but I get error "Access of undefined property on MouseDown". I have tried to abstract the issue as much as possible.  The command I am using to call my class is provided below. Thanks for any insights.

```
package  
{
import flash.display.*;;
import flash.events.*;;

public class MouseDraw extends Sprite {

    public function MouseDraw() {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);        
        }


    public function OnMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("mouse down");        
    }                   

}   

}
```

//code in fla

```
var mouseDraw:MouseDraw= new MouseDraw();
addChild(mouseDraw);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code: the name of your handler (`OnMouseDown()`) begins with a capital  letter, but you add an event listener on `onMouseDown`with a lower case. Rename your function to `onMouseDown` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Charles--I caught that just after posting.  But now i get new error  "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."  Any thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @user2066788 at which line do you get this error? Is it where you call `addChild()`? This is a method of a `DisplayObjectContainer` and we don't know on which object you call it. In your example, it is `this.addChild(mouseDraw)` (if you don't define on which object a method is called, it is `this` by default), but what's `this`? Have you tried `stage.addChild(mouseDraw)` ?

Comment: hi @user2066788I,  tried stage.addChild(mouseDraw) and I get the same error.  thanks

Comment: if you cant provide the line that error occured on, we'll struggle to help you

Answer (score 0):

wow--got this to work after mad googling.  thanks all who commented. Moral of the story--dont believe the code you see in books will compile!

```
package  
{
import flash.display.*;;
import flash.events.*;;

public class MouseDraw extends Sprite {

    public function MouseDraw() {

        graphics.lineStyle(1);

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);                       
        }


    private function init(e:Event):void {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,  onMouseDown);                    
    }

    private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("mouse down");        
    }                   

}   

}
```